# Where can I find NopCommerce plugins settings

Tags: nopcommerce

I can set the `Is enabled` property for NopCommerce plugins in Admin panel, but in which file (or DB table) can I do it programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check in plugin list and click on edit in plugin list in admin panel. there is enable option

Comment: Yes, that is the way to finish this job via Admin panel, but I needed to achieve this programmatically. Actually I found in my NopCommerce database corresponding table - [dbo].[Setting], and row with following name - 'widgetsettings.activewidgetsystemnames' that holds csv formated list of currently enabled plugins/widgets. Finally I added a sql script to update that field for my cusom created plugin. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a plugin type. A list of active payment plugins is stored into one setting, active widgets are stored into other one ('widgetsettings.activewidgetsystemnames'), etc